# Issue Importing Data to Matrix Fields With FeedMe Plugin

Tags: plugin-feedme

I am migrating content from a drupal site into Craft CMS. I am trying to using the FeedMe Plugin to do this.

Right now I'm working with a single test XML file to make sure my fields and setup are correct before I do the bulk import. However, my xml only ever creates the first matrix block. There is no limit to the number of blocks a user can include in the matrix block field I'm importing to.

The entry I am migrating content into has three tabs for fields. The main tab consists of the title and a matrix block. The third tab has a third party field "Legacy URL" from the Retour Craft CMS Plugin.

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<node_export created="Mon, 02 Oct 2017 00:15:47 -0400">
    <node>
        <title>Celebrating J Day</title>
        <nid>862</nid>
        <post_date>2017-09-22T00:00:00</post_date>
        <summary>A super summary.</summary>
        <storyBlock>
            <image>
                <image>http://website.com/path/to/my/image.png</image>
                <position>center</position>
            </image>
            <text>
                <text>Some awesome text is here.</text>
            </text>
        </storyBlock>
    </node>
</node_export>
```

My FeedMe field mapping looks like this:

[image]
[image]

The title, post_date, summary, and image matrix block all get imported properly. However, the text block and the nid into the legacy url field are not being imported.

The versions of everything:
FeedMe 2.0.7
Craft CMS 2.6.2991
PHP 7
MySQL 5.7

Does it look like I've set something up incorrectly? Any advice on how I can get this running correctly?

If any of the above is unclear, or if there is additional information I can provide, please let me know. I really appreciate your time and support!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been fixed in the latest version of Feed Me ([3.0.2.1](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me/releases) at time of writing). Do feel free to comment if not, or get in touch via the [Feed Me support channels](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/feed-me/docs/support/get-support)